# Reducing duplicate values in dataframe by pairs in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df_pairs

128.437     128.437     121.639  5100.9     5029.08   5029.08   4888.81  4888.81    0         0         0    0   0   0
129.588     129.588     122.79   5102.05    5030.24   5030.24   4959.55  4959.55    4889.96   4889.96   0    0   0   0
```

I'd like to keep all unique values in each row and reduce each repeated value to only 1 of the paired values.

The output would be:

```
df_unique

128.437     121.639  5100.9   5029.08    4888.81    0          0   0
129.588     122.79   5102.05  5030.24    4959.55    4889.96    0   0
```

So as you can see now each row has a pair/2 iff that pair is equal.

The pseudo code would be something like:

```
df_unique = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_pairs.columns)

for columns in range(len(df_pairs.columns)):

     if df_pairs.iloc[row_element] == df_pairs.iloc[row_element+1]:

             unique_element = df_pairs.iloc[row_element]
             df_unique[new_row_element] = unique_element
```

Is there any way to do this quickly without iterating by each pair row element-wise?

I cannot simply remove all duplicates with `df.drop_duplicates()` because of the fact that there may be repeating values in the rows that aren't necessarily neighbour pairs along with the fact that there are 0s that I want to keep in unique pairs if they occur.

Comment: The order must stay the same but with obviously shifted indices.

Comment: Are things considered pairs only if they are adjacent, or would `0 10 0` still have the 0 considered a duplicate?

Comment: No only adjacent pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.groupby(df.ne(df.shift(axis=1)).all(axis=0).cumsum(), 
            axis=1)
 .apply(lambda x: x.drop(x.columns[1::2], axis=1))
 .dropna(axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
          0        2        3        4        6        8    10    12
--  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ----  ----
 0  128.437  121.639  5100.9   5029.08  4888.81     0        0     0
 1  129.588  122.79   5102.05  5030.24  4959.55  4889.96     0     0
```